# React update UI after modal form submit

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a modal form on a page that you can add an item to a list, this gets saved in a SQL database. Sometimes the page updates right when you add an item, other times it saves it to the database but doesn't update the page until you refresh. I need to ensure it updates each time, looking for thoughts. Here is my current code.. Commented out places are things I have tried but failed.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, FloatingLabel, Form, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

import getAllRequests from '../../services/getAllRequests';
import createRequest from '../../services/createRequest';

const Main = () => {
    const [searchedMain, setSearchedMain] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [newRequest, setNewRequest] = useState({
        name: '',
        requestType: '',
        description: '',
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setNewRequest((prev) => {
            return {...prev, [name]: value}
        });
    };

    async function fetchData() {
        try {
            let data = getAllRequests();
            data.then((res) => {
                setSearchedMain(res.data);
                setLoading(false);
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // try {
        //     let data = getAllRequests();
        //     data.then((res) => {
        //         setSearchedMain(res.data);
        //         setLoading(false);
        //     })
        // } catch (err) {
        //     console.log(err);
        // }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const handleOpen = () => setShow(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleSave = () => {
        createRequest(newRequest);
        // setSearchedMain(prev => [...prev, newRequest]);
        // try {
        //     let data = getAllRequests();
        //     data.then((res) => {
        //         setSearchedMain(res.data);
        //         setLoading(false);
        //     })
        // } catch (err) {
        //     console.log(err);
        // }
        
        setShow(false);
        fetchData();
    };

    return loading ?
        <>
            <h1>Loading</h1>
        </>
        :
        <>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <Modal show={show}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Add Request</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <FloatingLabel label="Name">
                            <Form.Control name="name" onChange={handleChange} />
                        </FloatingLabel>
                        <FloatingLabel label="Request Type" className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Control name="requestType" onChange={handleChange} />
                        </FloatingLabel>
                        <FloatingLabel label="Description" className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Control name="description" onChange={handleChange} />
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form>  
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSave}>
                        Save Changes
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th onClick={handleOpen}>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {searchedMain.map((request, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index} request={request}>
                                <td>{request.record}</td>
                                <td>{request.name}</td>
                                <td>{request.requestedBy}</td>
                                <td>{request.description}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
}

export default Main;
```

The following worked the most consistent when running the handleSave

```
setSearchedMain(prev => [...prev, newRequest]);
```

But unfortunately it leaves off an auto-increment value needed when added to the DB, which is used for updates later. So being able to save to db, read from db and then render the updated results consistently is the most ideal situation.

Not show - attempted to have a variable inside my useEffect [] but I could never set one that would work. Either would not render or get stuck in an infinite loop of API requests.

Any thoughts/suggestions are greatly appreciated as I feel I'm going in circles.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed

- You are using a `<Form>` but not submitting using a `<button type="submit"` instead you have an `onClick` outside of the `<Form>`. I suggest picking an approach and sticking with it.
- You have onChanges attached to the inputs but no `value={}` - your inputs are not fully controlled.
- In your handleSave, you want to fetch the data after your promise has finished - try doing it in the `.then()`, otherwise you are refetching the data before the promise has had the chance to complete.
- A possible approach for this kind of thing is to let the server handle everything - i.e make the return of your save request/mutation have the same shape as the initially fetched data & just override your entire state with the response of the server (that would include your recently added/deleted element).

Just a few thoughts off the top of my head. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the form/submit feedback. Also added the value to each line.

Adding the .then in my handleSave has the same result as all the others, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Still in the same boat